# GNU Screen: How can I create a screen in the background if it doesn't exist?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

"screen -R -D -S test" will create a session named test if it doesn't exist, or connect to it if it does

"screen -d -m -S test" will create a new detached session named test, whether it exists or not, possibly leading to multiple sessions named test:

```
There are several suitable screens on:
    9705.test   (06/18/2012 06:42:58 PM)    (Detached)
    9639.test   (06/18/2012 06:42:57 PM)    (Detached)
```

How can I create a detached session named test, but only if one doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `-d -R` combination:

```
screen -d -R -S test
```

From `man screen`:

```
      -d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or  even  create  it
              first
```

**EDIT**

If you just want to create a background screen only if it doesn't exist, a little shell function in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc will work:

```
function bgsc { 
  if screen -list | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q "$1$"; then
    echo "screen $1 already exists" > &2
  else
    screen -d -m -S $1
  fi
}
```

Then just call `bgsc test`.

Comment: But I don't want to reattach, I just want to create it detached and _not_ attach to it.

Comment: @user939259: Ah, I misunderstood. I don't see anything in the manual, but I've updated my answer with a short shell function to create a new detached screen if it doesn't exist.